# Deploy Angular app to GitHub Pages without project name in the url

Tags: deployment, github-pages

I want to deploy my Angular app to GitHub Pages. But instead of `https://yourgithubusername.github.io/yourprojectname/`, I want something like `https://yourgithubusername.github.io`. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a project named `username.github.io` :

```
https://github.com/username/username.github.io
```

Your project will be deployed to `https://username.github.io` ( static page)

Check document [Websites for you and your projects](https://pages.github.com/).